# Is there a better method to achieve a plasma look?

Tags: shaders

[image]
[image]
[image]
This is my first attempt at creating a corona-treatment plasma. I used a principled volume shader and some noise but it's just not great. The third image is an actual picture of the plasma. Google "corona treatment" if you want more examples. Can you suggest a better approach? The object being 'treated' is a conveyor belt.